# How to get the program call stack trace?

Tags: events, abap

My program can be started in 2 ways:

the `START OF SELECTION` event that calls a `MAIN` function from one of my local classes.
the `ZAVGTTA4` transaction that calls the same method.

at `PAI`, for the BACK event, when calling `LEAVE TO SCREEN '0'.`, my program behaves in 2 ways according to how it was started. I want to get back to the selection screen (1000).

I thought about querying the stack, where i'm sure to find how my program was called. I can see that the stack trace is different, but i don't know how to acces my stack from the program. I've heard about the RTTI that i think might be able to help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try `SYSTEM_CALLSTACK`.

```
DATA:
   abap_callstack_line TYPE abap_callstack_line,
   callstack TYPE  abap_callstack.


  CALL FUNCTION 'SYSTEM_CALLSTACK'
    EXPORTING
      max_level          = 4
    IMPORTING
      callstack          = callstack.
```

But in your case I would prefer an additional parameter and the calling place can fill this entry. I would not call the parameter `called_by` but something like `behaviour` or `mode`.

Comment: Thx. that did it. Btw, with your explanation, do you mean that some data object called "behavior" be declared in the 'DATA' section, and some piece of logic be implemented? Cuz that's what i did. But if you meand something different (and you think it's really nice to explain :P ) please provide some more details. Anyway thx alot!

Comment: I have some  problems to give a correct example, because I did not really understand, how you call what. What are the two ways to call your programm? Via submit and with transaction `ZAVGTTA4`? The system field `SY-TCODE` contains the actual transaction. If `SY-TCODE = 'ZAVGTTA4'`, then your programm is called with transaction `ZAVGTTA4`.

Comment: I know it's already answered but I'm wondering what the value of variable `SY-CPROG` is too (that's calling program name).

Comment: There is also `SY-REPID` - the program name. I have no SAP-System available, so I can't check it, but I think `SY-REPID` is the actual report (called by `SA38` or direct per transaction). If you make make submits, `SY-CPROG` is the report "one level lower", `SY-REPID` is the first report.